# Enviornment broken after uninstalling Rails 6.0.0.rc1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spring

I ran
`gem uninstall rails -v 6.0.0.rc1`
`gem uninstall railties -v 6.0.0.rc1`
and even `rvm remove ruby-2.6.1`
then reinstalled ruby, created a new gemset but get this error on any `bin/rails generate ..` command (using rails 5.2.3):

```
Running via Spring preloader in process 25797
.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require': cannot load such file -- /home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/railties-6.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/commands.rb  (LoadError)
```

Answer (score 3):

Fixed by running

`spring stop`

from terminal